# Grep read form certain character/word to certain character/word

Tags: shell, unix, curl, grep

I use curl I want to get a certain phrase of it, the problem is that the entire file (that I am displaying using curl) consists of only 1 line.
The phrase I want to extract form this file begins always with `{"name":"headline","link":`
and it always ends with `}}`.

So the question is if there is any method to tell grep that it should display all the phrases which begin with `{"name":"headline","link":` until they end with the next `}}`?

```
curl http://example.org/file.txt | grep ?
```

BTW:

```
curl http://example.org/file.txt | grep "\{\"name\"\:\"headline\"\,\"link\"\:\"http\:\/\/"
```

Display the entire text file because it's just a one liner.

Comment: Thats a json string. Could you dump the full JSON here or in a pastebin then tell what type of output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
grep -o -E '"name":"Rausschmeisser","link":"[^"]+"'
```

This will give you a complete list of urls

```
egrep -o '"name":"Rausschmeisser","link":"[^"]+' | cut -f8- -d\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-o` option.

```
grep -o '{"name":"headline","link":[^}]*}}'
```

Alternatively, if you want only the stuff in between `{"name":"headline","link":` and `}}`, use Sed.

```
sed -r 's/{"name":"headline","link":([^}]*)}}/\1/g'
```

But really, get a proper JSON parser.